# Could not convert to MovieClip to ComboBox from multiple swc

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a AS3 project with swcA.swc and swcB.swc in it. swcA has a mc export for ActionScript class, named mcA.

mcA has a child combobox. swcB has the same situation similar with swcA, shown below:

```
swcA
    mcA (a definition)
       combobox (a child of mcA)

swcB
    mcB (a definition)
      combobox (a child of mcB)
```

And in my code: (3 situations)

1. `var m:MovieClip = new mcA(); // work fine`
2. `var m:MovieClip = new mcB(); // work fine`
3. `var m1:MovieClip = new mcA();`

   ```
   var m2:MovieClip = new mcB();  // trace type error:
                                  // it says xxxxMovieClip couldn't convent to xxx.xxx.Combobox;
   ```

My swc is very simple, just a MovieClip and some fl controls in it, and this MovieClip has a linkage name.

Because of designing UI layout is more easy in Flash author, I do not like code it.

And if other swc file that contain one or more fl controls wrap in MovieClip that has linkage name, it will cause error when compiling.

Comment: Did you do the same in your project? Coz the error says you can't movieclip to combobox. And there is no information about that lines.

Comment: yes, i did. TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@1f21adc1 to fl.controls.ComboBox.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()

Comment: this help:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962539/how-to-create-multiple-objects-from-multiple-different-swcs-which-implement-the)here. but I there too many fl controls in swc files

Comment: Actually, if you tried to do something like var cb:ComboBox = new mcA(); then only it will throw that error. Please check your code for that

Comment: Also it throws the same error if you assign a movieclip instance to a combobox variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the SWCs FLA files it's hard to tell, but I would have gone about it this way. But depends on design.

Place the combox components in the library, ensure linkage then export a single SWC called assets. Link the SWC up to your project.

In your AS3 then you can:

```
var mc1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var cb1:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
mc1.addChild(cb1);
addChild(mc1);
// Accessible via mc1.cb1. and cb1.
```

You can also do:

```
var sp1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cb2:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
sp1.addChild(cb2);
addChild(sp1);
// Accessible via sp1.cb2. and cb2.
```

I tend to use sprites over movieclips these days unless they are timeline based or heavily graphically customised.

Often flash bugs when creating assets when you switch it's type after creation. Eg movieclip from graphic. I tend to delete and recreate movieclip and place combobox inside it and assign linkage. This should be fine to assign to as many variables as you want then.

D

PS.

I just opened flash and created a movieclip (draw box select and press F8)

1. I set linkage name to "container"
2. Inside the movieclip I dropped a combobox and gave it an instance name (in the properties panel of "cb")

Then this code worked fine on the root timeline:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var mc1:MovieClip = new container();
addChild(mc1);

var mc2:MovieClip = new container();
addChild(mc2);

var mc3:MovieClip = new container();
addChild(mc3);

trace(mc1.cb); // Found [object ComboBox]
trace(mc2.cb); // Found [object ComboBox]
trace(mc3.cb); // Found [object ComboBox]
```

Comment: my swc is very simple. just a MovieClip and some fl controls in it, and this MovieClip has a linkage name. because of designing UI layout is more easy in Flash author, I do not like code it.

Comment: Additional comments in my answer in PS section.

Comment: FLA can be found at: www.aftc.co.uk/dev/eg.fla

Comment: Hmm. First example of yours does not make a nested combobox accessible via `mc1.cb1` but instead only as `cb1`, and as `mc1.getChildAt(0)`. Same with second example. Careful please.